# How can you use the coffeescript-maven-plugin to only run in a particular project?

Tags: maven, compilation, coffeescript

I am exploring using [coffeescript-maven-plugin by iron9light](https://github.com/iron9light/coffeescript-maven-plugin). Following the guide is pretty easy, and I can definitely use maven to compile my coffeescripts to normal Javascript.

Being new though to Maven, I have one small problem: My code is composed of two subprojects, one for the core (where Java classes are stored) and another for my UI (for JSPs, as well as my Coffeescript and Javascript files). It only makes sense to use this plugin in the UI project, of course, but I used this snippet of the plugin in the parent POM, such that it ends up trying to look for Coffeescript files in both subprojects.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.iron9light</groupId>
    <artifactId>coffeescript-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>

    <configuration>
        <srcDir>${basedir}/ui/src/main/scripts/coffee</srcDir>
        <outputDir>${basedir}/ui/src/main/scripts/coffee-build</outputDir>
        <modifiedOnly>false</modifiedOnly>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>coffeescript</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Because of this, when trying to run **mvn coffeescript:compile**, I get an error, i.e.,:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.iron9light:coffeescript-maven-plugin:1.1.2:compile (default-cli) on project test-core: Source directory not fount: C:\test\core\ui\src\main\scripts\coffee -> [Help 1]
```

If you will notice, it tries to look for a \core\ui\src... directory even when that directory does not exist.

Any tips/best practices how to resolve this? I just want it to compile Coffeescript files in the ui subproject, nothing more.

Comment: Why then not moving it to the concerned subproject instead of keeping it in the parent project/POM?

Comment: I tried moving the snippet into the subproject's pom, although running it returns "No plugin found for prefix 'coffeescript' in the current project and in the plugin groups".

Comment: did you move the whole snippet between the <plugin> tag? (the one you actually added to your question)

Comment: Yup. Am I supposed to leave something behind in the parent pom?